# How do I get the values of memory adresses used by apps outside of python (on MacOS)

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to use python to read the value of a memory address that another program is using and I haven't been able to figure out how to. (I'm using macOS)

I've tried many ways but I think the closest I've gotten is this because the [website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-value-from-address-in-python/) actually shows it working for them, but when i do it in python it just crashes.

```
import ctypes

x = "0x7FA09AAE85A0"
a = ctypes.cast(x, ctypes.py_object).value

print(a)
```

Comment: You shouldn't be able to access another applications memory on systems with virtual memory.

Comment: In that website, the examples are all within the same process.